# Compare self.parentViewController to a given UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Is it possible? That is, can I do something like this, which doesn't work...

```
if (self.parentViewController == CustomViewController) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

...to make, for example, a Settings panel look more like either of its possible parent controllers?  (Example again, if the menu is soft and light but the gameplay is kinda dark, it'd be convenient to say "if your parent is A look like this, but if your parent is B, look like this")

If it definitely can't be done, or if comparing the parentViewController to something else is dangerous/messy, I'll just set a flag `fromView` and code according to that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could go with `if([self.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[CustomViewController class]])`

Answer (score 0):

self.parentViewController returns NavigationController so it doesn't work, so I found other way, this worked for me:

```
unsigned long currentVCIndex = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self.navigationController.topViewController];

//previous view controller
UIViewController *view = (UIViewController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:currentVCIndex - 1];

if([view isKindOfClass:[CustomViewController class]])
{
    [self runSomething];
}
```